# Continue executing JS function based on Pop-up

Tags: javascript

I have a js function from inside this function I am calling a pop-up (includes some decision making let say Yes/No) where user can choose one option and based on that decision further function will be executed.

e.g.,

```
<!-- pop up HTML -->

1) Yes
2) No


// JS function

function myFn(){

       pop_up.open()  // pop up will open here where he either choose Yes or No



       If (user choose Yes){
          // execute this block
       }else{
          // execute this block
      }

  }
```

But I don't know How the instance of pop-up will be return to same function.

Comment: Can you show the `pop_up` logic?

Comment: @Curt It will be two buttons or two anchor tags nothing more , I haven't designed it yet So If I have to design pop-up with some caution I can do that

Comment: @saf JS logic, not design.

Comment: @sigod as I mentioned it in my question . It only includes two options Yes/No (these will be static)

Comment: @sigod If you want the exact situation then I can tell you , I am using D3 js graph library and where when user try to drag any node then a pop up will get opened which will ask him , he want to move the node or not and based on that further function will be executed

Answer (score 0):

I would've written it similar to this:

```
pop_up.open(function (result) {
    if (result) { // yes
    }
    else { // no
    }
});
```

But I don't know if your `pop_up` support this.

If you just starting your project you can write a wrapper for `confirm`. Here's not tested draft for you:

```
var pop_up = {
    open: function (callback) {
        callback(confirm('<message>'));
    }
};
```

Also, it's better to use [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (with [shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim)) instead of pure callbacks.

Comment: I was thinking about using  bootbox library

Comment: Or, obviously, use some library.